# Unable to connect to mysql in NetBeans(11.3)

Tags: mysql, macos, netbeans, connector

I have the following :

- NetBeans IDE(11.3),
- mysql 8.0.20mysql-connector-java-8.0.20,
- mysql-8.0.20-macos10.15-x86_64. on macOS Catalina 10.15.5

While setting up conn via NetBeans I get the following
[Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aTvy.jpg)

I have seen a lot of posts and have gone through the installation and configuration docs but I am just unable to figure out what needs to be done.

URL --> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqlzeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL

ERROR: Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.) –

Comment: This may be a silly question, but do you have MySQL running?

Comment: Yes. Mysql is running and I checked the SYSTEM-timezone  variable it shows 'CEST' which is in sync with my laptop.  So I am just unsure what to do next.

Comment: Can you paste the URL in text here, please? And the full error text? And the username (not the password :) It seems your link has cut it short, and Stack Overflow does not allow code/text in images.

Comment: URL --> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL    ERROR: Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)

Comment: It has to be in your post :) Not in a comment. You can edit your Question.

Comment: sorry:( new to stackoverflow. thanks:)

Comment: @JoachimRohde Yes it works.  did a "SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+2:00'; " & "SET PERSIST time-zone = '+2:00';" and it worked.  thanks so much. also thanks a lot@Scratte.